# How to get the filename of a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have a C++ Windows application myapp.exe which loads several plug-ins.

Plug-ins need to find the path to their DLLs. I can use GetModuleFileName for this, but it need the handle for the plug-in DLL. I don't know where to get this handle. GetModuleHandle(NULL) returns the handle to the executable.

One option is to use GetModuleHandle (GetModuleHandle("myplugin.dll") ) , but this requires the name of the plugin to be hardcoded which I want to avoid.

Any help is appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I don't know where to get this handle

It's passed as a parameter to your DLLMain() entry function.

If the plugin can't access its DLLMain() entry function, it can use the VirtualQuery function on a piece of its own memory and use the AllocationBase field of the filled-in MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION structure as its HMODULE.

Comment: Perfect thank you Chris.

Here is the function I use:

HINSTANCE GetMyModuleHandle()
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    VirtualQuery(GetMyModuleHandle, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
    return (HINSTANCE) (mbi.AllocationBase);
}