# MFC: How to get DLL file name?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mfc, filenames

I have an MFC DLL that is loaded by a 3rd party application. How can I get the DLL filename from within the code of the DLL?  That is, for example, if the DLL's name is mycode.dll, in code I want to be able to retrieve the string "mycode.dll".

I should add that if the DLL file name is changed on disk then I would like to get the current name on disk (I don't mean changed during run-time but changed between invocations of the main program).

My DLL is implemented as a CWinApp class, my code has no explicit DllMain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the filename of a DLL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846044/how-to-get-the-filename-of-a-dll)

Comment: it's not really a duplicate of that because the OP has made it clear he doesn't have a `DllMain`.

Comment: Also it's not a complete duplicate because this is in the context of MFC which has different data and functions available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`AfxGetStaticModuleState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc6feexs.aspx) to get a pointer to an `AFX_MODULE_STATE` structure, which has a member `m_lpszCurrentAppName` containing the module name (app or DLL depending on where it's called from).

Comment: I'll try this, also this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268005/afxgetappname-returns-garbage-characters/1268074#1268074) says: The AfxGetAppName() function returns AfxGetModuleState()->m_lpszCurrentAppName.

Comment: @User, there's a difference between `AfxGetModuleState` and `AfxGetStaticModuleState`.

Comment: Actually, I just tried AfxGetAppName() and it does give me the DLL name minus the dll extension (which is fine).  I renamed the DLL and re-ran it and it gave me the new name so this seems the best way unless you know of a reason not to use it.

Comment: @User, is the calling app MFC as well? Unless you call AFX_MANAGE_STATE then AfxGetModuleState will return the app's parameters, not the DLL's. AfxGetStaticModuleState will always return the DLL's parameters if called from within the DLL.

Comment: I'm not sure if the calling app is MFC or not as it's 3rd party app.  I had assumed so, but I don't know.  In any case, it's doing the right thing.  It's definitely not returning the name of the 3rd party exe.

Comment: I see a visual studio note about "If this DLL is dynamically linked against the MFC DLLs, any functions exported from this DLL which call into MFC must have the AFX_MANAGE_STATE macro added at the very beginning of the function." However, my DLL is statically linked with MFC.

Comment: @User, then you're probably fine. If the app is using MFC it will be using a separate copy and the two won't know about each other, so AfxGetModuleState can only return the state it knows about i.e. your DLL.

Answer (score 1):

See the Get [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

When you pass in NULL for the first parameter, it will just use the handle for the current process.

Comment: My reading of the documentation for that function is that it would return the name of the exe that loaded the dll, not the name of dll, no?

Comment: It says: "Retrieves the fully-qualified path for the file that contains the specified module. ..." So I think it's used for modules. We have used this at work in the past, and It worked fine.

Comment: It further has documentation on some global pointer (defined in tchar.h) that helps you to get the full path of the executable of the current process.

Answer (score 1):

GetModuleFileName function definitely returns the EXE THAT LOADED THE DLL... not the DLL itself.  I would have posted this as a comment above but I don't have enough points yet, meh.